# Having trouble returning data from ajax post to self

Tags: jquery

I am trying to post a form to self that would work with javascript disabled, or with ajax if javascript is enabled.

The following example works if javascript is disabled, but I get no `response` returned on success using ajax:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['form'])) {

  $return['msg'] = 'congrats. it was posted to self';

  if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
    echo json_encode($return);
  }

}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#test-form').submit(function(e) {

  var postTo = location.href;

  var formData = $(this).serialize()+'&ajax=true';

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: postTo,
    data: formData,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response); // Not getting anything here
      $('#test-form-response').html(response.msg);          
    }
  });

  e.preventDefault();

});

}); // End doc ready

</script>

<form id="test-form" method="post" class="validate">
  <input type="hidden" name="form" value="test">
  <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="test-form-response"><?php if (isset($return['msg'])) { echo $return['msg']; } ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is here is when the request is Ajax then terminate the script after echo the `JSON` data

```
if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
    echo json_encode($return);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: your form is submitted by default prevent it by adding : e.preventDefault(); in your jquery form submit function